# How to perform Unbound Expression and set that value in bounded column?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

My Task is, I have two bounded columns(DiscountPercentage and DiscountAmount). If I change values in DiscountPercentage automatically DiscountAmount calculated and shown and same If I change DiscountAmount I need to calculate DiscountPercentage. So I Created two Unbounded Columns(Percentage, Amount) I calculate there through Unbound Expression. But I wont set If i click "Tab" button on keyboard. Then I created "FocusedRowchanged" event and wrote code there to set values in Bounded column. It set when i go to next row. But I need to set/Update while changing current cell to next cell immediately.

my code is

```
private void gridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // % to amt

        object obj = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["DiscountPercentage"]) == DBNull.Value
                            ? 0
                            : (gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["DiscountPercentage"]));
        decimal a = Convert.ToDecimal(obj);
        if (a > 0)
        {
            percentage.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Decimal;
            percentage.UnboundExpression = "[UnitPrice] * ([DiscountPercentage] / 100.0)";
        }





        // amt to %
        object dm = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["DiscountAmount"]) == DBNull.Value
                            ? 0
                            : (gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["DiscountAmount"]));
        decimal a1 = Convert.ToDecimal(dm);
        if (a1 > 0)
        {
            amount.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Decimal;
            amount.UnboundExpression = "Round(([DiscountAmount] / [UnitPrice]) * 100.0, 2)";
        }
    }




    private void gridView1_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // % to amt
        object obj = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["DiscountPercentage"]) == DBNull.Value
                            ? 0
                            : (gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["DiscountPercentage"]));
        decimal a = Convert.ToDecimal(obj);

        if (a > 0)
        {


            object obj2 = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["gridColumn1"]);
            int aa = Convert.ToInt32(obj2);
            gridView1.SetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["DiscountAmount"], aa);
        }


        // amt to %
        object dm = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["DiscountAmount"]) == DBNull.Value
                            ? 0
                            : (gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["DiscountAmount"]));
        decimal a1 = Convert.ToDecimal(dm);
        if (a1 > 0)
        {
            object obj3 = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["gridColumn2"]);
            int aa2 = Convert.ToInt32(obj3);
            gridView1.SetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["DiscountPercentage"], aa2);
        }

    }
```

Eg if Price = 1000 DiscountPercentage = 5 then automatically DiscountAmount set to 50
DiscountAmount = 100 then automatically DiscountPercentage set to 10

I need to perform this in the same row ? How to complete my task ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the data source? A DataTable or a List<T>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without using unbound columns, here is an exemple (I've tested it and it works fine)

```
private void gridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var row = gridView1.GetFocusedDataRow();

    // Calculating the dicsount %
    if (e.Column == colDiscountAmout)
    {
        var productPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(row["Price"]);
        var discountAmout = Convert.ToDecimal(row["DiscountAmout"]);
        row["DiscountPercent"] = (discountAmout * 100) / productPrice;
    }

    // Calculating the discount amount
    if (e.Column == colDiscountPercent)
    {
        var productPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(row["Price"]);
        var discountPercent = Convert.ToDecimal(row["DiscountAmout"]);
        row["DiscountAmout"] = productPrice * (discountPercent / 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi SidAhmed, Thanks for answering. I have doubt, I attached data's from Access Database. so I get error on this line "Product" What is Product here if I attached DataSources ? `var product = gridView.GetFocusedRow() as Product;`

Comment: Product is the name of an exemple class, You should replace it with the name of your table in the dataset

Comment: Hi SidAhmed, In my Dataset also name of the table is Product but Still same error ? "are you missing a using directive or an assemble reference"

Comment: May be your are missing a using directive as the error message said. What is the namespace of your DataSet ?

Comment: "InvoiceDataSet.xsd" name of my DataSet. In that Dataset I have Table called "Product", that product table i attached to GridItemLookUpEdit in the 1st column of gridView.

Comment: InvoiceDataSet is the name of the dataset, not the namespace. The namespace is where the dataset is located in the solution (ex : MyApplication.Data). Try clicking on the Product word (where the error is), and then press (Alt + Shift + F10). See what it propose.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42841/discussion-between-sri-hari-and-sidahmed)

Comment: What is "GetFocusedDataRow" here ? Is it dataSource name ?

Comment: Hi, SidAhmed Thanks a lot. Finally i got output what i except.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `.AcceptChanges()` on the underlying datasource during the `DataGridView.CellEndEdit` event.

Comment: Hi drankin2112, I didn't have that method "AcceptChanges" Am using a new tool called "DevExpress"

Comment: DevExpress is the vendor for the grid control. Is ADO.NET the underlying data storage platform? `AcceptChanges` is available in `System.Data.DataSet` and `System.Data.DataTable`.

Comment: How are you loading data into the control?

Comment: By choosing Data Source in Property of gridCOntrol

Comment: What is the DataSource? Is it a `DataSet` or a `DataTable` or a `DataView`?

Comment: Dataset, i include tables to Dataset from MS Access Database

Comment: Figure out how to enter the `ColumnView.CellValueChanged` event of your DevExpress.XtraGrid control. Then, from inside that event call `((DataSet)gridControl.DataSource).AcceptChanges();`